Can I drill a larger hole in a sistered 2x10 joist?
I’m replacing the old plumbing in my 125 year old house and am trying to do it as by the book as I can. I have talked to a structural engineer, and am working with an experienced plumber, but I just want to make sure I’m ok.
So 3 of my 2x10 (more accurately they’re like 9 1/4-9 1/2) floor joists have been notched every wrong way possible over the years, and I plan to sister them before running a new toilet drain through 2 of them. The two problems I keep running into in my plan are that a) the 3 5/8 hole required to run the 3” PVC is over 1/3 of the depth of my joist even if I call it a 10in joist, and b) to run the line at the correct slope, I will end up drilling through the second joist outside of the middle third by a little over half an inch.
Sistering was the solution the structural engineer suggested for this problem when he looked at it, so am I supposed to assume that the doubled joist has a bit more wiggle room to it? Just want some reassurance before I really get started here.

If you're really worried about it you can use something like these guys to help: https://metwood.com/product/joist-repair-hole-reinforcer-2810hr/

Let's assume you had those joists break and/or rot away.  What would you use to replace them?  Use that as a sister joist.  Since you're having slope issues with plumbing, would it be possible to have the drain pipe run "under" the joist, instead of through it?

Think about it this way:
If you double it up it's twice as strong, so your hole can now come within 1/6 of its height of the edges - or something like that: I'm not an engineer.

Basically true. But it sounds like the sistering is also to compensate for all the existing problems.

True if the existing joist is worthless  would need to sister twice to get the performance I describe
